# Ant Design: How to pass this.props.form to children

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a form and each Form.Item is a separate componenent, looks like the below

```
  <Form>
  {this.props.children}
  </Form>
```

How can I use this.props.form in the children since it is only created in Form component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in your render method if you wanted to pass down `this.props.form` to the children:

```
render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, { someForm: this.props.form })
    );

    return <Form>{childrenWithProps}</Form>
}
```

Then in your children component you can access the prop via `this.props.someForm`, for example.